# Downloading Images from URL in PHP

Tags: php, image, curl

I have a file, where I read URLs line by line. The URL are links to images. All the image-links work in the browser. Now I want to download them to my current directory. For the record I need to use a PHP-script.

This is how I get my Images:

```
for ($j; $j< $count;$j++)

{
  // Get Image-URL as String and then do getImage
  $image = $arr[$j];
  $newname = $j;
  getImage($image, $newname);
}

function getImage($image, $newname)
{

    $ch = curl_init($image);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $fp = fopen("$newname.jpg",'w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

But the problem is, I get all the images, only the last one is viewable. The others I can't open and they only have **1KB**.

So what did I do wrong?

Plus I need to also download png-Files later on, so can I then just change the **$newname.jpg** into **$newname.png**?

Thanks in advance, I really need an answer fast, been sitting here for hours, trying to figure it out.

Comment: what do you have inside of $arr ?

Comment: What's the starting value for `$j` ?

Comment: $j probably starts at null, which means 0 in norwegian. :)

Comment: This is only a snippet. $j starts at 0 of course. in $arr are the urls, from the file. They are true, I echoed them and they were alright, so no problem there.

Comment: @OIS that is not 100% true, but in this context you are right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [stream_copy_to_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php)?

```
function getImage($image, $newname, $fileType = "jpg")
{
    $in = fopen($image, "r");
    $out = fopen("$newname.$fileType",'w');
    stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out); 
    fclose($in); fclose($out);
}
```

You can also play with [stream_set_read_buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-read-buffer.php)

```
stream_set_read_buffer($in, 4096);
```

Just tested this with our avatar pics.

```
$data = [
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/42eec337b6404f97aedfb4f39d4991f2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2700a034dcbecff07c55d4fef09d110b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
];

foreach ($data as $i => $image) getImage($image, $i, "png");
```

Works perfectly.

Debug: Read the remote headers for more info?
[$httpresponseheader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)

```
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

or [stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/stream_get_meta_data)

```
var_dump(stream_get_meta_data($in), stream_get_meta_data($out));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before, and now tried it again. When I do this, I get following Errors:    Warning: fopen(IMAGEURL ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\Imagescale\functions.php on line 93                                                                                                                   I edited the Warning message, I replaced the url from the image with IMAGEURL in fopen()

Comment: Can you open the image in an incognito browser window without logging in anywhere? Can you get it with cli curl? Can your PHP download external files?

Comment: Icognito Browser works. As I said before, with curl I get one image working, which is the last one. With the others I get new files, but they are not working, and only 1kb big.

Comment: @DerrickRose The 403 is from the remote server. Maybe your URL needs to be properly encoded. %20 for space, etc. Is the url displayed in your browser the same as the one in your input data? Maybe you can check if the contents of the 1kb big files is a 403 html page?

Comment: yes, they stay the same, and they have no special characters, except " _ ", but I don't think this is a problem.

Comment: @DerrickRose Try reading the response headers. Added some code to help debug.

Comment: Warning: stream_copy_to_stream() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Imagescale\functions.php on line 104

Comment: Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Imagescale\functions.php on line 105

Comment: And the HTTP header is too long to post here

Comment: array(13) { [0]=> string(22) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" [1]=> string(13) "Server: nginx" [2]=> string(35) "Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 13:48:42 GMT" [3]=> string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" [4]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [5]=> string(44) "X-Pingback: http://blog.jimdo.com/xmlrpc.php" [6]=>  }

Comment: This is the first part

Comment: 404 means the file is not on the server. Without the img url noone can help you. If it works in your browser then it is probably an encoding problem.

Comment: Okay, but I used url_encode() now. And I just tried it with some other images: http://www.modny73.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Eco-Green-Logos61.jpg  and  http://www.thegreatcourses.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x600/0f396e8a55728e79b48334e699243c07/1/8/1884---base_image_4.1424267632.jpg

Comment: Ok I have been narrowing it down now, I tried it, like you did, so no reading from a file, just putting in the URLs in an array. Then it worked. So I guess I have a problem when I read the URLs from my file and store them in an array.$handle = fopen("images.dat", "r");
    $arr = [];
    
    define('MAX_WIDTH', 600);
    define('MAX_HEIGHT', 600);
 while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
 {
        $url = urlencode($line);
          echo $url.",";
        array_push($arr, $url); 
    }